# Cluster Variables Against Single Outcome Variable - ClustOfVar

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I have a dataset with variables representing both scores and traits (mix of qualitative and quantitative on both counts).  I want to cluster the traits (not the individual observations) according to each of the scores.  So, I want to form clusters of traits (trait_1 through trait_15) that are similar on the basis of score_1, then repeat for scores 2 and 3.  Example of the data structure below.

I am thinking that I can use the ClustOfVar package to form these clusters, which I would understand if I were just trying to cluster all of the variables into like groups.  However, I don't know how to cluster them on the basis of one of the other variables.

If anyone has suggestions, I'd appreciate it.  Thanks in advance.

```
Score_1 Score_2 Score_3 Trait_1 Trait_2 Trait_3 …   Trait_15
```

n1
n2
n3
…
n100000

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look into *subspace* clustering algorithms.

They usually allow *overlapping* clusters, so you may get out quite a number of clusters.

You cluster on the traits only, then check if the found clusters correspond to your known scores in a second phase.

Comment: Thanks for the advice - any particular packages or functions you would recommend?

Comment: I do not use `R`. I like efficient algorithms, R is popular in a community that tries to solve everything by matrix multiplication.